# android asynctask with threading

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created an asynctask and in its doInBackground() method i started a thread like this:

```
private class myAsyntask extends Asynctask{

    doInBackground(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     public void run()
     {
        while(someBoolean!=true){
        Thread.currentThread.sleep(100);
        } 
     }
     });
    }
   onPostExecute(){
  //do something related to that variable
  }
}
```

problem I am facing is after 1st iteration of `Thread.sleep()` , `onPostExecute()` is called , instead I thought that asynctask will run this thread on background and when that boolean is true onPostexecute() is called.I am not able to understand why this happens ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AsyncTask automatically creates a new Thread for you, so everything you do in `doInBackground()` is on another thread.
What you are doing is this:

1. AsyncTask creates a new Thread and runs `doInBackground()`.
2. a new Thread (`t`) is created from the AsyncTask-Thread.
3. `doInBackground()` is completed, as all it does is create the Thread t and thus jumps to `onPostExecute()`.
4. Thread t would still be running in the background (however, you do not call `start()` on `t`, meaning that it is not started).

Instead you want your `doInBackground()` method to look something like this:

```
doInBackground(){
    while(someBoolean!=true){
        //Perform some repeating action.
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice i understood what the problem is now.

Comment: @user1254554 Good :) You should accept an answer (by clicking the checkmark under the score on the left) if it helped you. This both closes the question and gives a reward to the person answering.

Comment: Does the `Thread` in `doInBackground()` here point to the background thread? I hope it won't block the UI.

Comment: yes, using the `Thread.sleep()` method affects the thread that calls the method. Since it is called in `doInBackground()` it is the background thread that sleeps. That is - it does not block the UI.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in your code you don't even start thread `t`, so all that happens in `doInBackground` is creation of new thread and then moving on to `onPostExecute()`.

Secondly, you don't even need separate thread, since `doInBackground()` handles this for you, so you can just use something like

```
doInBackground(){
    while(someBoolean!=true){
        Thread.currentThread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

if you wish, however, to stick with separate thread, you can start thread and wait for it's completion by using [.join();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) like

```
doInBackground(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(someBoolean!=true){
                Thread.currentThread.sleep(100);
            } 
        }
    });
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I now understood the problem

Answer (score 1):

`onPostExecute` can only be called when `doInBackground` has `return`-ed. In your code, the only possible way this can happen is `sleep` throwing an `Exception` (`InterruptedException`??)