# Android: HTTP requests in AsyncTask are not concurrent

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I'm writing a fan app for [my local cinematheque](http://www.sderot-cin.org.il/info/about/about-003.htm), which shows the screening calendar for the next few days. The per-day film list is retrieved using a [parametrized HTTP call](http://www.sderot-cin.org.il/cgi-webaxy/sal/sal.pl?ID=839468_cinematheque&act=search2&dbResOptions=hideResTabTitle=0&getValueAJAX=dataid,f1,f2,f3,f4&dbid=shows2009&query=sort%3CD%3Ef3%3CD%3Esort2%3CD%3Ef4%3CD%3Ef2%3CD%3E8/11/2012%3CD%3Ef2%3CD%3E8/11/2012) from the site (The answer contains Hebrew, so if you clicked the link and got some Gibberish it's probably OK).

The app displays the schedule for the next eight days, so It makes 8 calls with per-day schedule request.

```
private class GetMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Film>>
```

`doInBackground()` retrieves the list of films per day, and `onPostExecute()` updates the interface.

The AsyncTask is called from `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DAYS_TO_VIEW; i++){
    new GetMoviesTask().execute(i);
}
```

The problem is that AsyncTask is not executed concurrently. The days are slowly loaded one after another, which is painfully slow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's the best way to start these AsyncCalls concurrently?

Comment: Why does it have to be Parallel? Why not hit it in sequence?

Comment: @st0le I would consider sequential HTTP calls a professional embarrassment in this case. Why keep the user waiting for `8*(TIME_PER_CALL)` when I can serve the info in `~TIME_PER_CALL`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AsyncTask` has been known to hit a regression in Android 4.x, where the system executes them *one at a time* instead of executing them concurrently as it did since Android 1.6. This is by design: basically, on newer platforms, you can revert to the old concurrent behaviour by calling `executeOnExecutor()` instead of `execute()`. Mark Murphy (known as [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) on StackOverflow) has [all the details sorted](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html) on his blog.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks fo the link!

Answer (score 0):

Basically AsyncTask only creates one thread for you which runs on the background.

You can achieve what you want in two ways.

- Firstly you can create separate AsyncTasks for each of the operations.
- Secondly by creating multiple threads in your doInBackground method and making concurrent requests and processes.After that you can notify your UI by publishing those to onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute.

Check this

[android asynctask with threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939143/android-asynctask-with-threading)