# Android HTML Jsoup parsing speed

Tags: android, performance, web-scraping, jsoup

Here is the deal. In my android app I'm doing some web scraping with Jsoup. Now it works fine, but its too slow. What I'm doing in my code is:

1. Login to the page via POST method in Jsoup;
2. Get the cookies;
3. By reusing the cookies I'm going through 6 pages (POST and GET) and scraping them (mainly tables and lots of rows. I mean LOTS... so, really many foreach loops);
4. Writing all required data to SQLiteDatabase;

Now the problem is that it sucks at speed. I mean, in the login screen of the application after pressing the login button, user have to wait up to 10 seconds in 3G and ~8-10 sec in WiFi (depending on WiFi speed). And when he tries to check for data updates it does the same algorithm + comparing SQLiteDatabase table data.

So, is there any alternative way to do this HTML parse - scrape thing in android to make it faster ? P.S. I do NOT have access to the database sadly.

**EDIT:**

Since you asked about the content I'm scraping, here is the one example of few pages you can access without logging in (it is not really a big table compared to others ): https://medeine.vgtu.lt/programos/programa.jsp?sid=F&fak=5&prog=87&rus=U&klb=en.

Now, for the code... I really cannot give you the full code, but here is the example how I'm getting each cell of the table:

```
document = Jsoup.connect(getContext().getString(R.string.url))
                    .cookie("JSESSIONID", cookie)
                    .get();

            Element table = document.select("table.duomenys").first();
            if (table != null) {
                databaseHandler.openDatabase();
                databaseHandler.getDatabase().beginTransaction();
                try {
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr.n, tr.l") {
                        Elements columns = row.select("td");
                        addItem(columns, DatabaseHandler.getTableName());
                    }
                    databaseHandler.getDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    databaseHandler.getDatabase().endTransaction();
                }
                databaseHandler.closeDatabase();
            }
```

And here is the addItem() method example:

```
private void addItem(Elements columns, String tableName) {
    databaseHandler.addItem(new Item(
            columns.get(0).text(),
            columns.get(1).text(),
            columns.get(3).text(),
            columns.get(4).text()
    ), tableName);
}
```

And it's just a one page. There are 6 of them and few of them are lot bigger. Of course this is done inside AsyncTaskLoader's loadInBackground() method.

**EDIT 2:**

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://medeine.vgtu.lt/studentams/submit.jsp")
                .data("studKnNr", id, "asmKodas", password)
                .timeout(3000)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        String cookie = response.cookie("JSESSIONID");

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(modules_url)
                .cookie(cookie_id, cookie)
                .get();
```

When I think about it... could it be that not the parsing is slow, but logging in  and redirecting through 6 pages and in that case I can do nothing ? Now I noticed that sending POST to server via .execute() in Connection.Response and and getting the cookies took ~ 2.5 sec.

Comment: `Writing all required data to SQLiteDatabase`  `I do NOT have access to the database`  ????

Comment: I'm writing downloaded data to my own SQLiteDatabase. By not having access I mean I do not have access to that website's database, so I HAVE to scrape the website.
To be very clear, I'm scraping the university information system website, and they not granted access to their database yet.

Comment: If your code is to slow then you should post your code here and put one page somewhere on the internet so we don't have to login but can do some testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your question is ambiguous and you did not provide your code, neither some samples of the DOMs you are parsing, I will provide a general answer.

- Optimize your jsoup query. Since there a lot of data (big DOM), try
  to parse them as efficiently you as you can.
- Minimize loops. Are you sure you are not doing any unnecessary loops
  during the handling of the data?
- If by any chance you concatenate big chunks of strings then try using
  `StringBuilder` instead of `String`.
- Try using multiple threads.

**Update**

You can receive the server's response, manipulate the body of the message and then use Jsoup's parse so you can minimize the time of the parsing.

```
try {
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("ENTER_URL")
                                   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                                   .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
                                   .method(Method.GET) //or Method.POST
                                   .execute();

    String body = response.body();

    String table = body; //Manipulate the string, remove all the data you don't want.

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(table);

    System.out.println(doc);

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update 2**

`Connection.Response line takes 2.6 seconds`: this cannot be helped. You have to live with this, since it's the server that delays to serve your request. After all you take the cookies only once and then reuse them.

However this part `getting the page` can be optimized to some extend. If you use the code I posted, you will still have the overhead of making the http request again (this cannot be avoided, it's the server delay as with the cookies), but you will only parse the part that you need, instead of the whole response. This will give you some improvement but I don't believe it will be much. Maybe it's not even worth it. But you can try to change this part only, and tell me if you see any improvement.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(modules_url)
                .cookie(cookie_id, cookie)
                .get();
```

Moreover you will have to use some form of concurrency (multiple threads), if you really need the speed. 
Something like this will make a real difference:

1. Retrieve the cookies (only once, in the beginning) in the parent thread.
2. For every page create a new thread and pass the cookies and the url
   as arguments.
3. Every thread parses the page that was assigned to it.
4. All the data are gathered in the parent thread.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329537/android-http-requests-in-asynctask-are-not-concurrent) selected answer on how you can make your http request concurrent

Comment: For efficiency of parsing DOM: Is there any way I can parse table only ? Because Jsoup.connect().get() parses the whole HTML page and just then it starts scraping it. I need table only.

Comment: Yea, but you see when I log in, I MUST redirect to another page instantly and that I'm doing by sending GET method, so .get() is used anyway. Check EDIT 2 for my login code. And this .body() code I think would work only for non-login pages in my case.

Comment: In EDIT2 you do two things. First you get the cookies and then you get the page (modules_url). Both of them take 2.5 seconds? Or just the part that receives the cookies?

Comment: Connection.Response line takes 2.6 seconds, resopnse.cookie() takes 1 ms. And getting the page I redirected 1.5 s. So it takes 4.1 seconds before I get page content.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will let you know if there was improvements in a few days. Secondly, is concurrent threading works with loader ? And last question is can I maintain session for as long as user uses app? Because on website user is automatically disconnected if he/she is not active for 10 minutes(I mean can I reuse cookies as long as I want with jsoup or it will be "out of date" after 10 minutes of inactivity ?).

Comment: For the concurrency part, you'll have to do some research, since I haven't encountered it. For the second part, no if you don't do something about it. The session will be invalidated by the server. There is a solution though. You could send periodically (let's say every six minutes) dummy request (OPTIONS or HEAD method, these two are low overhead requests) so the server will not kill the session. Jsoup is a parser, so it only supports GET and POST, so if you want to do this, you will have to implement it with something else (like httpclient, that jsoup uses underneath)

Comment: Awesome answer , This answer save my a lots time