# Application keeps opening by itself

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an Android app and I've encountered the following problem: Everytime I close the app or it crashes, a few seconds later, it opens again, all by itself.

I've narrowed the problem the PlanItApp class, wich inherits from Application. All the login process is done in that class and, when it finishes, I call de Main activity from this same class. Here's the troubling part (this an inner class **inside PlanItApp** wich is used to retrieve data from the server):

```
public class BaseAsyncDataRetriever extends AsyncTask<PlanItApp, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PlanItApp... params) {
        setContacts();
        PlanItApp app = params[0];
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                invitedEventsAux = toLinkedList(PlanItApp.client.getUserInvitedEvents(PlanItApp.PIiD)); 
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        });
        t1.start();
        try {latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        super.onPostExecute();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);           
    }   
}
```

And, if I comment out *startActivity(i);* the app won't open by itself. Even if onPostExecute() is called and Main activity is opened, if I close the app after, it will open itself a few seconds later.

Since I have absolutely no clue what the problem might be, I don't know what other piece of code might be relevant. Any insight could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The problem was that on the onCreate() method from the PlanIt class I called an async class wich would, eventually, start the Main activity. The problem was that, when the application was closed, the OS would re open it (this happens to every other process) and call the onCreate() method again, and reopen the app. This is the reason why there is a launcher class.

The solution was to move the activity instancing logic to the launcher class, which doesn't get called everytime the app is closed, only when the user opens it.

Answer (score 3):

It finishes the execution of `doInBackground` and then moves into `onPostExecute` which calls `startActivity` eventually. You closing the app doesn't change anything, once the background thread finishes, `onPostExecute` automatically gets called.

On top of my head, try to keep a global boolean for successful operation in `doInBackground` and only if it's set then call startActivity which of course must be unset in `onPause()` or `onStop()`.

There might be better solutions though.

**Update:** Do you really need that new Thread? You know, `AsyncTask` automatically creates a new `Thread` for you, so everything you do in `doInBackground()` is already on that thread.

If you need to have a new `Thread` inside `doInBackground()`, the proper way to do it is to wait for it to finish and call `join()` for that thread.

Here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9939285/655987)

Comment: Actually, even if onPostExecute() is called and Main activity is opened, if I close the app after, it will open itself a few seconds later.

Comment: Oops... Sorry for deleting the previous comment. I'm very confident this is what happens, by the way. Maybe there are some other calls to **this** AsyncTask?

Comment: OK, you have another Thread inside doInBackground. What does it do exactly?

Comment: It just retrieves some info from the server, but I use a CountdownLatch to keep the background thread waiting for this thread to return.

Comment: It seems your background thread starts a new thread and carries on (calls `onPostExecute`). Doesn't wait it to finish.

Comment: Even if I delete all the threads inside DoInBackground(), the problem is still not solved.

Comment: From the code you provided, either it is impossible or I'm not able to pinpoint the exact cause of these multiple calls to `onPostExecute()`. If you share the code in which you create the instance(s) of this class, then I might be able to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58650/discussion-between-santiago-marti-olbrich-and-0x5f3759df).